# In Euclid' s Elements, why is $\frac{\sqrt{a^ 2 - b^2}}{a}$ important in the definition of "apotome"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry

Although I had originally found them in Book X of Euclid's Elements, there is a summary of the definition of [apotome](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Apotome) on the web.  After sifting through the definitions there are 4 conditions Euclid checks:

- only $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ **or** only $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ **or** $a,b \notin \mathbb{Q}$
- $\frac{a}{b} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ but $(\frac{a}{b})^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ (always)
- $ \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{a} \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $ \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{a} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ **WHY IS THIS CONDITION SO IMPORTANT??**

Between the first and third items there are six possibilities.  Here are examples of each kind:

1. $9 - \sqrt{17}$
2. $2 \sqrt{3}- 3$
3. $\color{lightgray}{\sqrt{11} - \sqrt{\frac{143}{49}}}$
4. $3 - \sqrt{2}$
5. $\sqrt{13}-3$
6. $\sqrt{7} - \sqrt{5}$

**Related question** Is there example of 3rd apotome of the form $\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{n}$ with $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

> $\boxed{3\sqrt{2}-10}$ any others??

Comment: There's two definitions.  The **apotome** which requires $( \frac{a}{b})^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ - that rules out a lot of numbers - and confusingly, the **first apotome** which involves the ratio $ \sqrt{1 - (\frac{a}{b})^2} \in \mathbb{Q}$.